# OrientDB Security - Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, rest, orientdb

We are using OrientDB Server as our DB for our mobile Application.

Since we are using Javascript and REST Api for communication between OrientDB and our Application, our username and password is not secure because any user can view source and see all our account credentials to access orientDB.

How are we going to handle this situation? That we can secure our server to anonymous users??

Thanks!

Any reply is very much appreciated.

Comment: I fail to see the difference between , if the site(client) accesses your DB directly and a user. Why not like anyone else. Login, get a session cookie, let server side handle the security of connection to DB

Comment: Having the same issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30380909/create-a-user-with-java-with-lowest-rights-in-orientdb but till now I didn't check with the latest OrientDB release. Maybe it's fixed right now.

Answer (score 1):

You should use some backend technology/framework to abstract direct access to OrientDB so that users can't manipulate your database directly. You can try to look at [node.js](http://nodejs.org/) for example if you like to work with JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

You can ask to the client to enter username/password and just let a "guest" user to see the public pages.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend not having the front-end communicate directly with the database as this would make it harder to secure and harder to protect against injections.

Using some back-end code would be better suited to communicating with the database.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the default username and password to the reader ORole, which will only allow reading the database, they can't write anything until they register and login. After they register and login their own password will be used instead of the default one. At which point you just need to setup databases as ORestricted.

The ORoles should allow you to setup the users in such a way that even if they see the various database entries, they can only delete their own entries, not other authors. The database will check every time a command is received to see if the user is allowed to make that change. Look at [Record Level Security](http://orientdb.com/docs/2.0/orientdb.wiki/Security.html#record_level_security) for a more detailed explanation.