# Create a user with Java with lowest rights in OrientDB

Tags: java, database, orientdb, rights

I create a user with lowest rights in the following way:

```
            db.command(new OCommandScript("sql", "insert into orole set name = 'ardaRole', mode = 0")).execute();
            db.command(new OCommandScript("sql", "update orole put rules = 'database.class', 2 where name = 'ardaRole'")).execute();
            db.command(new OCommandScript("sql", "update orole put rules = 'database.function', 2 where name = 'ardaRole'")).execute();
            db.command(new OCommandScript("sql", "update orole put rules = 'database.cluster', 2 where name = 'ardaRole'")).execute();
            db.command(new OCommandScript("sql", "insert into ouser set name = 'arda', password = 'arda', status = 'ACTIVE', roles = (select from ORole where name = 'ardaRole')"))
                    .execute();
```

That works pretty well. If you want to check the rights in my project check out: http://arda-maps.org:2480 with *arda arda*.

So my issue is that these rights still allow things like **changing the name of a vertex** (so I changed LOVES to LOVESd). But that is killing the whole database structure and functions!

So how can I restrict the rights even more? This is really bad, because I want to give anyone access to the database. But noone should be able to change anything there just read... There must be a way...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that it works in the way above. This is just a bug or a temporarly change for the specific user and isn't further harming the database. So the code is totally fine.