# First time OrientDB user regarding security in REST api

Tags: rest, orientdb

I am new to OrientDB. I am going thorugh the REST apis and I am not able to understand the security of the apis. I dont have much experience with backend development (i am a front end developer) so please help me clarify some points here :

- As I can see all the GET requests are open, as in, if I know the url & the record or class name I can simply type it in the web browser & anyone can access all the records. How does this data is protected ??
- How does access tokens or session works with the REST Apis ??

This might be a very basic question but since I have just started learning it please suggest the right approach or any useful resources.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

all REST requests are authenticated using HTTP authentication, if you have OrientDB Studio open then you are already authenticated and the browser will not ask again for user/password. Try to open a new anonymous browser window and send a REST call, you will see the popup asking for user/password.

Here you can find additional info about HTTP and sessions

http://orientdb.com/docs/last/OrientDB-REST.html

Comment: Ok so this means I can assign each application user a unique user name and password. But I can only find the connect call.. I dont understand how can I register a username & password in my database for a new user from the app using REST api ?? Also how can I assign certain role to this user ??

Thanks for the answer though. If this last thing gets sorted I'll mark it as the right answer. This question again may sound silly but please consider it coming from a complete beginner.

Comment: I think you have a very similar question like I had: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30380909/create-a-user-with-java-with-lowest-rights-in-orientdb Still no solution for mine. Could you tell me if your issue is the same.

Comment: Even with HTTP authentication, you do not want to leave your web server open to the public web. See this question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36028628/server-security-and-accessing-orientdb-via-rest/54710677#54710677

Comment: To register a new user, you just have to do an INSERT on OUser class, same for roles (ORole). The password is encrypted automatically, so you can insert it in plain text the first time (there is a hook for this). The assignment between the two is just a link. See the records for built-in system users, it's pretty simple