# Server security and accessing OrientDB via Rest

Tags: orientdb

Guess this is an embarrassing beginner question,anyways...

In the OrientDB documentation under "server security" we find:

> While OrientDB Server can function as a regular Web Server, it is not recommended that you expose it directly to either the Internet or public networks. Instead, always hide OrientDB server in private networks.

Does this mean that the port 2480 which OrientDB uses for listening to HTTP connections should be open only locally but not being exposed to the outside world?

Comment: It should be exactly as you said

Comment: Thanks for clarification, Alessandro. My thinking was that a rest api should be reachable over the internet. But it is possible of course to provide the api via Node/Express for example which is internally connected to the database.

Comment: I wondered about this too, but I don't understand how to open an HTTP connection locally on a web server. Do I have to make a second Rest API that communicates to the localhost?

Answer (score 0):

The OrientDB HTTP API documentation states that you have to use HTTP Basic authentication for issuing commands. That means you have to include an Authorization header along with your request.

Below are some links that might find useful in which it is discussed the safety issue:

[Security concern](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/orient-database/BXDuzJ3AHUc/8gxca2hTCdgJ)

[security-in-rest-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30601601/first-time-orientdb-user-regarding-security-in-rest-api)

OrientDB v2.2 is very focused about security, tt was made a step forward in this direction (SALTed passwords, encryption at rest (DES/AES on storage), disabled of access to OUSer, mask of passwords on Server's console and salted password also in the server).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a reverse proxy to "hide" your OrientDB server from the public web. I am on an AWS AMI Linux machine. Using httpd I created a file in /etc/httpd/conf.d called virtualhosts.conf. How you set up virtualhosts may depend on your linux flavor. Contents of virtualhosts.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
    LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so
    ServerName orientdb.mydomain.com
    DocumentRoot $ORIENTDBHOME$/www 
    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:2480/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:2480/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.mydomain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www
</VirtualHost>
```

Substitute $ORIENTDBHOME$ with the path to your OrientDB install. So my subdomain orientdb (orientdb.mydomain.com) forwards to the OrientDB server at port 2480 but the browser maintains the orientdb.mydomain.com URL. I followed the instructions [here](https://www.linuxjournal.com/content/protect-your-ports-reverse-proxy), but also added a virtualhost for my main domain.

Update:
Do the same Proxy settings for  in your ssl.conf file if you have an SSL certificate for your subdomain and you have it set up as a virtualhost. (Copy/paste the last three lines from the above VirtualHost into your virtualhost for SSL).

Update 2: You probably don't even want to expose the *:80 one to the public, but it's shown for demonstration. You probably can also forward to https, but you'll have to keep looking for that solution.